# Full form of matching methods for " matchTemplate" available in OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv, correlation, cross-correlation, pearson

I know this is a noob question to ask, but i had to. I got confused with these matching methods `matchtemplate ()` parameters full form.

> **parameters =['cv2.TM_CCOEFF', 'cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED', 'cv2.TM_CCORR','cv2.TM_CCORR_NORMED', 'cv2.TM_SQDIFF',
>   'cv2.TM_SQDIFF_NORMED']**

I want to know which of this Normalized cross Correlation method? Is it 
`**cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED**` or `**cv2.TM_CCORR_NORMED**` . What is the full form of `**cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED**` method. Does it mean "Pearson Correlation" or "Correlation Coefficient"?

Comment: How about [checking the doc](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/object_detection.html?highlight=matchtemplate#cv.MatchTemplate) ?

Comment: @remi- I have already referred that, But it doesnot specify the full form of all those methods.

Comment: Its does specify the formula for computation. I dont know the formula for what you expect. Based on the name I would say CCOEFF_NORMED = normalized correlation coefficient, CCOOR_NORMED = normalized cross correlation, but you have to check if the formula given in the docs is really what you expect

Comment: @remi- Thats all i wanted, I wanted to know whats CCOEFF_NORMED. And your answer did help me. thanks for it.